# What do Markov operators do?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

A discrete time Markov process is a random variable $X:\Omega\to S^\infty$ on a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \{\mathcal{F}_n\}_{n=1}^\infty, P)$such that $P(X_{j+1}\in H | \mathcal{F}_n)=P(X_{j+1} \in H | \sigma(X_j))$ where $S$ is a countable standard Borel topological space with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

We may define a discrete-time Markov process via a Markov transition matrix (kernel function) $K \in \mathbb{R}^{|S|\times |S|}$. That is,

$$K(a,b)=K_{a,b} =P(X_{j+1} =a | X_{j+1}=b) \quad \forall a,b \in S.$$

From this Markov transition matrix, we may obtain a Markov kernel that is, a map
$\kappa:S\times \mathcal{A}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that

- For every $x \in S, \kappa(x, \cdot)$ is a probability measure.
- For every $A \in \mathscr{A}, \kappa(\cdot, A)$ is measurable.

for $B\subset S, a\in S$, $\kappa(B,a)=\sum_{b\in B}K_{a,b}$.

The kernel function defines a linear operator $T:L^1(S)\to L^1(S)$ as

$$Tf(x) = \int_SK(x,y)f(y)\nu(dy)=\sum_{y\in S}K(x,y)f(y)$$

where $\nu$ is the counting measure.

This Markov kernel is the kernel of an integral operator. **What is the integral operator doing to these functions in terms of a stochastic process?** I only know of operators in the context of "the structure presesrving mappings between Banach Spaces" and it is suprising that we can characterize a markov process by kernel which in turn defines an operator. To me, it seems like the operator is the interesting structure, and we just access it using the kernel, but I'm not sure what its use is.

Is there maybe some interesting way of viewing this in terms of the theory of distributions or functional analysis?

Comment: I think you are assuming the set $S$ is finite or countably infinite. Otherwise your $K(a,b)$ function, which seems to be defining conditional probability masses, would not be a suitable description of the Markov chain.

Comment: @Michael yes, thank you I am assuming that

Comment: I do not know what is meant by $v(dy)$ where $v$ is the counting measure. Do you really mean that $T f(x) = \sum_{y \in S} K(x,y)f(y)$?  In general it seems silly to use a general integration sign $\int_S$ when you are talking about a finite or countably infinite set $S$. Overall, this looks like "Markov chains made hard."

Comment: @Michael Yes I was trying to put it in a more general setting.

Comment: Let $X(t) \in S$ denote the state of the DTMC at time $t$.  Then your $T$ operator is taking an input equal to the PMF of $X(t)$ and outputting the resulting PMF of $X(t+1)$. It is equivalent to $$P[X(t+1)=j] = \sum_{i \in S} P[X(t)=i]P_{ij} \quad \forall j \in S$$ where $P_{ij}=K(j,i)$ is the transition probability.

Comment: Thank you!! This totally is intuitive and is exactly what I was looking for. How can this extend to continuous time processes? It feels like when I apply an operator, I increment time by one unit, but time is continuous.

Comment: If you only look at times when the CTMC transitions, then you really have an embedded DTMC and the $T(\cdot)$ equation is the same as before.  You could use notation like $X_k=X(t_k)$ where $t_k$ is the time of the $k$th transition, and then $\{X_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ is a DTMC. Else, you need to define $K(a,b,\tau)=P[X(t+\tau)=a|X(t)=b]$ to specify how much time $\tau>0$ you are considering. Then your $T(\cdot)$ should really be $T_{\tau}(\cdot)$ to specify what $\tau$ you are using.

Comment: @Michael Ok, so essentially, the operator determines "Over this amount of time, for this input, where is the distribution sent". When I use DTMC, and I apply the operator, this is one unit of time, and similarly, I could say $T_2(f(x))=T(T(f(x))$ and so on

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Michael Ok I understand now thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize my comments as an answer: If we let $X(t) \in S$ be the state of the DTMC then your $T(\cdot)$ operator takes a potential PMF for $X(t)$ as the input (at some time $t$) and gives output equal to the resulting PMF for $X(t+1)$.  It is the same as the equation
$$ P[X(t+1)=j]=\sum_{i \in S} P[X(t)=i]P_{ij} \quad \forall j \in S$$
where $P_{ij} = K(j,i)$ is the transition probability from $i$ to $j$.

---

For CTMC: If you had a CTMC $X(t) \in S$ then you could look at the embedded DTMC $\{X(t_k)\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ where $t_0=0$ and $t_k$ is the time of the $k$th transition.

Alternatively, you could define a function
$$K(a,b,\tau) = P[X(t+\tau)=a|X(t)=b] \quad \forall a,b\in S, \tau>0$$
Then your $T(\cdot)$ can be modified to $T_{\tau}(\cdot)$ to specify how much time $\tau>0$ you are considering.